# How to remove the third party plugin in magento 2 completely?

Tags: magento2

I have disabled the weltpixel owl carousel, but i want to completely remove it from the magento. how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Disabled the the extension by command:

> ```
> php bin/magento module:disable {Vendorname}_{Module}.
> ```

Then remov it composer package from composer.json using

> ```
> composer remove {YourmoduleCoposerapckageName}
> ```

like `composer remove magento/module-catalog` for catalog module

Then delete all files from folder if you have

Now do indexing  & di compile and static content deploy.

**Note That :Please take a full back of system before  trying it**

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed it using composer then you can remove using command below :

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall Module_Name
```

However if not installed using composer then you have to disable that module first, then upgrade and compile your code and finally remove module in app/code/ModuleUninstallFolder and entry remove entry from app/etc/env.php